# Unable to locate p tag element on page with Selenium

Tags: jquery, css, selenium, xpath

I am sorry for coming to you guys for help for such a simple operation, but I have literally exhausted all my tools trying to figure this out. I have tried locating by partial xpath, full xpath, various css selectors.

I want to know how to locate this element which seems to be jquery related and interact with it.

HTML of the portion of the page that is relevant is below:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend class="hidden_visually">Choose Your Reload Amount</legend>
    <div class="predefined_amount_selector">

    <div id="Predefined_Reload_Amount">
        <ol class="selector numbers form">
                <li>
<input aria-labelledby="defined-amount-label_0" class="radio" id="defined-amount_0" name="defined_amount" title="$10" type="radio" value="10" />
                    <label for="defined-amount_0" id="defined-amount-label_0" class="">$10</label>
                </li>
                <li>
<input aria-labelledby="defined-amount-label_1" checked="checked" class="radio" id="defined-amount_1" name="defined_amount" title="$25" type="radio" value="25" />
                    <label for="defined-amount_1" id="defined-amount-label_1" class="">$25</label>
                </li>
                <li>
<input aria-labelledby="defined-amount-label_2" class="radio" id="defined-amount_2" name="defined_amount" title="$50" type="radio" value="50" />
                    <label for="defined-amount_2" id="defined-amount-label_2" class="">$50</label>
                </li>
                <li>
<input aria-labelledby="defined-amount-label_3" class="radio" id="defined-amount_3" name="defined_amount" title="$100" type="radio" value="100" />
                    <label for="defined-amount_3" id="defined-amount-label_3" class="">$100</label>
                </li>
        </ol>
        <p class="note">Or enter your own amount &raquo;</p>
    </div>

    <noscript>
        <p>Enter the amount you'd like to load on this card.</p>
    </noscript>

    <div id="Manual_Reload_Amount">
        <ol class="form form_full">
            <li  id="min_max_amount" data-min="5" data-max="100">
                    <span class="numbers">$</span>

<input class="field_small numbers align_right" data-validation-max="100" data-validation-min="10" id="reload_amount" maxlength="10" name="Amount" title="Please enter an amount." type="text" value="25" />
                <span>$10 to $100</span>

            </li>
        </ol>
        <p class="note">Or choose an amount &raquo;</p>
    </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to locate?

Comment: *"Unable to locate p tag element on page with Selenium"*. Without more specific info on which `<p>` exactly that you want to get, the answer would be just `//p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this with jquery. I have put together a sample for you

https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/ro50jw14/

You will just need to change the selector to whichever paragraph you are trying to access

Comment: I am rather new to Jquery. I believe I will just use the javascript inject from Selenium with code that clicks this paragraph? Does jquery have the ability to click?

Comment: You can easily do that with JQuery, a pretty simple task to accomplish. I have modified the code. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/ro50jw14/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! There ended up being a few other p tags on the page, so I just changed the selector to be $( "p:contains('Or enter your own')" ).click()